# Mod_rewrite for single.php

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to use mod_rewrite to show pretty urls in my urls:

Instead of
.../juegos/plants-vs-zombies/?play=jugar
change to
.../juegos/plants-vs-zombies/jugar/

And 
.../juegos/ddtank/?play=full
change to
.../juegos/ddtank/full/

I use the file "single.php" with this code:

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query); 
$parametro = $query['play'];

if ($parametro == 'jugar')
{
    include( get_template_directory() . '/single-play.php');
}
else if ($parametro == 'full')
{
    include( get_template_directory() . '/single-full.php');
}
```

And in .htaccess I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)play=jugar($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /jugar/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

But when I try to get the url with /jugar/ and /full/ at the end of the url, it displays an 404 error.

I don't know what else to do. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Mod_rewrite doesn't work on PHP includes.

Comment: If Mod_rewrite doesn't work on PHP includes, do you know any other way to load the custom post file depending if the file single.php receive the parameter "play"?

Comment: if it displays an 404 error. that means it thinks that full and jugar are directories @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Comment: did you try this http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/ @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward to me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?juegos/plants-vs-zombies/jugar/?$ /juegos/plants-vs-zombies/?play=1 [END]
```

For that to work the rewriting module has to be installed and enabled, obviously. The rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration and in a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess`). If you decide to use a dynamic configuration file, then you need to place that in the http hosts document root folder and enable its interpretation using the `AllowOverride` directive in the host configuration.

If you receive a http status 500 using the above rule ("server internal error") chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try replacing the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

what the browser sees `/juegos/plants-vs-zombies/jugar/`,

what the server sees `?play=juegos/plants-vs-zombies/jugar`

after explode it changes to an `Array ( [0] => juegos [1] => plants-vs-zombies/ [1] => jugar)`

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?play=$1 [NC]
```

This to change`$_GET['play']` to an array

```
$play = explode("/", $_GET['play']);


 if(isset($_GET['play'])){
    $play = explode("/", $_GET['play']);

    //if you want to add `/` at the end
     if(end($play) == ""){
        array_pop($page);
    }
 }
```

## [Passing Query String Parameters in WordPress URL](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/)

Comment: does the rewriting module work, also why do you use `TEMPLATEPATH` @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Comment: do you want `?play=1` to be seen as `jugar` ? @Fernando

Comment: I use TEMPLATEPATH to load different custom post file (if the url has ?play then loads "single-play.php", and if the url doesn't have anything, then loads "single-clic.php".

Comment: That's why in single.php I have this code: if (isset($_GET['play']))
{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-play.php');
}
else 
{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-clic.php');
}

Comment: I always have a 404 error when I try to load the page with this url: http://www.juegoskids.com/juegos/plants-vs-zombies/jugar/   but with this works fine: http://www.juegoskids.com/juegos/plants-vs-zombies/?play=1 but I want to use pretty URL, I don't want to show the parameter ?play in the urls

Comment: how do you serve this URL http://www.juegoskids.com/juegos/plants-vs-zombies/ @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Comment: do all requests go to  juegoskids.com/index.php @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Comment: I serve that url with single.php (it's a post from wordpress)

Comment: what happens when you use my Answer @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Comment: if you do that `?play=jugar ` You will get the URL you want @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Comment: You are so close now! I tried but it sends to main page followed with the parameter, by example: http://www.juegoskids.com/?play=juegos/plants-vs-zombies/jugar/    I did that after change the content of single.php using explode with your example (but with explode I don't receive the third parameter "jugar", i got: [0]=juegos [1]=plants-vs-zombies [2]=VOID

Comment: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/ @Fernando Lozano Hernández

Comment: I edited my post in order to update what I've done. I hope you can help me.